# How do I create space in my mix (example provided)

Tags: mixing, post-production, reverb, space

It seems no matter what I try I cannot recreate or even get close to the mix I desire. A mix where all my sounds are clean yet full and have the depth I desire. Over the years I have used many software plugins but finally what is left in my arsenal in the waves version 9.2 suite for basically all my mixing needs and occassionally fab filter. I know a good mix requires good sounds upfront,I can make my sounds hit the way I want and sound the way I want, but when it comes to that space around them I have hit a dead end. An example of what I feel has this space I desire

any tips on getting that space? This is the first time I have ever reached out for some help, usually finding my answers off this forum from previous posts, but never answering my question that I cannot accurately ask being I don't really know what it is. Any tips would be extremely appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Could you perhaps post a clip with one of your mixes that lacks the space you seek?

Comment: Space is usually created by enough high frequencies, use of stereo image and well set effects like reverb and hall. Example of your work would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a great plug-in that I use called **DrMS by Mat Lane** that is an amazing spacial processor that I use for adding space and depth to my mixes. 
It can be used for mixing, mastering and post production.
It has a great load of presets which suit just about any application, or you can dial in your own to suit your taste / style.
I have tried just about every MS spacial processor out there on the market and I find this is without doubt the best yet, without making your mixes sound airy or phasey. My favorite preset is 'Honey In The Middle'...I use it on just about all my mixes and I often get asked how I get so much space in my mix.
**It is one of my favorite plug-ins**, & I have hundreds of them.

Comment: Wow thank you. This sounds great.  Thank you man.